# Error LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol _HUGE referenced in _luaopen_math

Tags: c++, c, lua

I got error when I finished revising some things. Also I already searched here but this error is different because it was **LUA**

This is the error i got

> Error 17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __HUGE referenced
>   in function _luaopen_math C:********\lua52.lib(lmathlib.obj) ELS-CF_1

Thank You! and have a good day

Answer (score 2):

`__HUGE` symbol defined in `LIBCMT.lib`. Check that you linked against this lib. If you need to ignore `LIBCMT.lib` you could try to define `HUGE_VAL` value in your code. Math library used it in `lmathlib.c` at `lua_pushnumber(L, HUGE_VAL);`